# Global background color change windows 8 app using MVVMLight

Tags: .net, user-interface, windows-store-apps, mvvm-light

I am looking for a simple solution for changing the background color of my application across all pages from various points in the View Models. I am using MVVMLight Windows 8.1 project template and following most of the patterns out of the box. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Why didnt you use resources in the app.xaml for consntant valirables? I think this is the most elegant way, what you can do it int this situation, or adding resource files. That is better maybe.